# How to load RSA key pair without Openssl or other Library

Tags: c++, c, rsa, public-key-encryption

CCFor a project I was searching for a simple RSA implementation to exchange a small secret via an unsecured but existing communication protocol. To keep it small and easy to portable to different platforms I did not want to link against OpenSSL or Crypto++. I found that as a part of the [axTLS](http://axtls.sourceforge.net) project which has a suitable license and an easy to extract RSA algorithm. The rsa function for encryption needs two components (as it usses the public key). The pup_exp is 65537 and modulus is the public part of the key and priv_exp the private one.

```
void RSA_priv_key_new(RSA_CTX **ctx, 
        const uint8_t *modulus, int mod_len,
        const uint8_t *pub_exp, int pub_len,
        const uint8_t *priv_exp, int priv_len
    )
```

For easy use for the user, I want to load a certificate like X.509 or PEM generated by a library like OpenSSL, but in C or C++ code without including the whole OpenSSL stuff. But at the moment I even did not find an understandable documentation of the common key file formats.

Comment: They're based on ASN.1 (a sort of binary XML for structured data) so you should start with a library that does that for you at least. Once you've got that you should be able to load the binary key (or base64-encoded key) into a tree structure and then just find the correct OIDs for the key parts you want, which are probably easily found in the OpenSSL code or by comparing output from an OpenSSL key dump to console.

Comment: axTLS claims to handle X509v1, PKCS#8 and PKCS#12 formats. That is all you need. Unfortunately most certificates are X509v3 so you have to be careful there.

Comment: @GregS Yep your answer here is the right one. I found the parsing routine, they a not really beauties but they will fit my need (I hope). Thanks for the hint and the warning.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of RSA public key format widely used and they are PKCS#1 and X.509(SubjectPublicKeyInfo).
I have used libtomcrypt(http://libtom.org/?page=features). It supports both the RSA key formats and very much portable. The license is non restrictive.

Comment: I already tried libtom(crypt). You are right, the license is non restrictive, but my try to reduce the libs only to the routines I need failed.